# What is the graphics technique for drawing 3D holes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

How to draw a circular disc with thickness and then "drill" holes (of any shape) into it at runtime? 
The desired outcome would look like CAD drawings without textures.

I am using OpenGL, but I guess this is independant of the graphics API.

Comment: You can use stencil operations to do this kind of things. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. I have been reading them, trying to understand. I am holding it a while longer to capture more answers, hopefully this will be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you're after is [Constructive solid geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry). Some current graphics/game engines (like [Unreal](http://www.unrealengine.com/)) use it, but most don't  do the real thing but approximate (fake) the results with textures or switching a solid geometry with a prepared multipart model. Another approach would involve using voxels, like Minecraft or [Voxatron](http://www.lexaloffle.com/voxatron.php/).

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCSG](http://www.opencsg.org/) should do what you want.

Look into CGAL innards of [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) if you need the CSG'd geometry and not just a rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an interesting use of [Geometry Shaders](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/geometry-shader/).  Take in the disc geometry and add the extra vertices for the holes and then pass to the Fragment Shader.